# Scanning a string from a file ignoring the last character

Tags: c, string, scanf

Edit: Oops, forgot to say this is C

I have a .txt file with the following:

```
    blabla, 213, 32
```

I want to store the first string in a variable, so I do this:

```
    char x[6];
    int y, z;
    fscanf(finput, "%s, %d, %d", x, y, z)
```

but when I print "x" I get:

```
    blabla,
```

and the rest of the text does not get stored correctly.

What I find weirdest is that my array `x` has the same number of "spaces" as `blabla` has characters, but it still stores seven characters.

A workaround would be to read each character and store them individually, but I would like to do it as a string if possible.

Comment: C-"strings" are `0`-terminated, so one always needs one element more then one would like to use. Try: `char x[7]` to read `"blabla"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this line

```
fscanf(finput, "%s, %d, %d", x, y, z)
```

should be fixed to eliminate undefined behavior:

```
fscanf(finput, "%s, %d, %d", x, &y, &z)
//                              ^   ^
//                              |   |
// You need to take an address of int variables
```

If you do not want the comma to be included in your string, use `%[^,]` instead:

```
fscanf(finput, "%5[^,], %d, %d", x, &y, &z)
//                ^^^^
//                 ||
// This means "read characters until you hit a comma
```

Note that I added `5` to limit the length of the string being read to six `char`s.

Finally, to see if the `fscanf` returned a proper number of items, get its return value, and check if it's equal to the number of items that you expected:

```
int count = fscanf(finput, "%5[^,], %d, %d", x, &y, &z);
if (count == 3) {
    // All three items are there
} else {
    // We did not get enough items
}
```

Comment: If I'm sure it will be 6 characters long and before a comma, can I use only `%[^,]` or `%5s` (If the second one is possible)?

Comment: @Ciscool If you are sure that it is at most 6 characters, you need to declare `x` as `char x[7]` for the null termination of the string. Using `%6[^,]` is safer than `%[^,]` although it's OK to use it when you know for sure that the input will never exceed the allocated size (for example, because you wrote the program that wrote that file). Using `%s` will not work; `%6s` may work, but then all strings will have to be exactly 6 characters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I understand. Any idea why it stores more than 5 characters if I declared as `char x[6]`? I'm using CodeBlocks with GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: @Ciscool `fscanf` has no idea of `x`'s declaration. All it knows is what you tell it in the format string. It thinks that `x` that you pass is a pointer to `char`, not an array of six chars. That is why if you wish to add a limit, you need to do it in the format string.

Comment: @Ciscool: Buffer overflow -- anything might happen.  In this case it appears to work because there's unused padding space allocated after the array.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is an array of exactly 6 characters. You cannot store more than that on static-allocated array.

Comment: "*... cannot store more  ...*" not even that but one few then the array's size!

Comment: Just tried it again, it stores 7 characters. In my code it is actually inside a struct. Does it change something?